# Colored box around hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I would like to highlight with a colored box the hyperlink to an url in the text as well as
the hyperlink to tables, figures and references as in the following example:

Since I'm pretty new in latex, does anybody help me please?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Example]

Comment: hyperref package should do what you want here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\section{Example with \textit{hyperref}}

and the associated clinical information were downloaded \\
(GEO,\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/}{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/})\\
selected data are shown in Table \ref{tab1} . Information \\
and associated host genes was retrieved from miRBase 

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
one & 1 \\
\hline 
two & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

the result

[image]

Comment: Rather than `\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/}{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/}` you could use `\url{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/}` (but, with the default settings, that changes the font).